# Callback function that returns an array off all posts on a wordpress blog with a given category

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, wordpress, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a callback function that returns an array of all the posts of a given category from a wordpress blog so i can pull this data into a static site compiler.

[The API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/) only returns 100 at a time so i have to loop through them page by page and add them to an array.

I've managed to loop through them and log them to the console but i can't work out how to add them to an array while using promises. I'm not sure what arguement i should pass to `push()`

any pointers would be appreciated.

```
const getData = (category, number = 0, page = 1) =>
  fetch(`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.accessaa.co.uk/posts?category=${category}&number=${number}&page=${page}&order_by=date`)
    .then(res => res.json())

const found = (category) =>
  getData(category)
    .then(json => json.found)

var total = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(found('news'))
})

var times = total.then(function(value) {
   return Math.ceil(value/100)
})

var calls = times
  .then(function(callsToMake) {
    items = []
    for (i = 1; i < callsToMake; i++) {
      getData('news', 100, i)
        .then(json => json.posts)
        .then(items.push(posts))
    }
    return items
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some of the code structure for readability purposes.

The solution to your problem is to make a pool of asynchronous tasks and then run them in parallel. `Promise.all([promises])` is perfect for the latter because it will return an array of the resolved values until all of the promises have been successfully resolved or one of them has rejected.

```js
const getData = (category, number = 0, page = 1) =>
  fetch(`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.accessaa.co.uk/posts?category=${category}&number=${number}&page=${page}&order_by=date`)
    .then(res => res.json())

const found = (category)=> getData(category).then(json => json.found);

found('news')
.then((value)=>{
    return Math.ceil(value/100);
})
.then((callsToMake)=>{
    let tasks = [];
    for (i = 1; i < callsToMake; i++) {
        tasks.push(getData('news', 100, i)) //<--- Fill tasks array with promises that will eventually return a value
    }
    return Promise.all(tasks); //<-- Run these tasks in parallel and return an array of the resolved values of the N Promises.
})
.then((arrOfPosts)=>{
    let allPosts = [];
    for(var elem of arrOfPosts)
        allPosts = allPosts.concat(elem.posts);
    
    console.log(allPosts);  
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare "posts":

```
.then(json => json.posts)
    .then(posts=> items.push(posts))
```

Or simply:

```
.then(json => items.push(json.posts))
```

B.T.W: 'var total' is weird. you're rapping A promise with a promise